# expression language... how to add quotes around a resolved expression?

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I'm new to .jsp and servlets and have an Expression Language question.  In my java servlet file, I set an attribute:

```
HttpServletRequest request;
....
request.getSession().setAttribute("myValues", "TEST");
```

Then in my .jsp file, I'm trying to call a function that processes the attribute value:

```
    <script>
        myForm.initSelect( ${myValues} );
    </script>
```

When I look at the deployed results in the Java console, the ${myValues} EL has resolved to just TEST (no quotes) and I get a TEST is undefined error.  I would like the results to show:

```
myForm.initSelect( "TEST" );
```

where I am passing the value "TEST" (as a quoted string) into my initSelect function.

I have tried adding quotes like:

```
myForm.initSelect( "${myValues}" );
myForm.initSelect( \"${myValues}\" );
```

and some other variations using single quotes, but those don't give the expected results.  Can anyone please provide some suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: `myForm.initSelect( "${myValues}" );` is right. What does it do wrong? What output do you get? Of course, if the actual value contains a double quote (`TE"ST`, for example), the generated JS will be incorrect. Properly JS-escape the value to avoid this problem.

Comment: `request.getSession().setAttribute("myValues", "\"TEST\"");`

Comment: @JBNizet, Thanks.  I was seeing something weird in that the ending quote was disappearing... but it turns out I had a tons of spaces in the string that I was storing the attribute, so the closing quote was just pushed really far off to the right.  How do I mark a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: myForm.initSelect( "${myValues}" ); is correct, it will work, what you want using this and what you are not getting using this, post that which might be actual cause of issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the `myForm.initSelect( "${myValues}" );`

It will be evaluated to

myForm.initSelect( "ABC" );

if you have `request.getSession().setAttribute("myValues", "ABC");`